# Extract arabic-numerated pages with qpdf

Tags: qpdf

The file `srcfile.pdf` has a variable number of roman-numerated pages (i, ii, iii, etc) and the following arabic-numerated pages (1, 2, 3, ..., n).

How to extract only arabic-numbered pages (e.g. #1 to #10)?

The following command extracts pages i, ii, iii, 1, 2, etc.

```bash
qpdf --empty --pages srcfile.pdf 1-10 -- targetfile.pdf
```

Is it possible to extract only pages 1, 2, 3, etc.?

Comment: I don't think it can be done with qpdf. You can do this with cpdf like this: `cpdf in.pdf [1]-[10] -o out.pdf`. The `[]` tells cpdf to use labels not serial numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`qpdf` has an option `--json` to generate a json representation of the file.

With this option there is a workaround using a json parser like e.g. [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

With the following bash script "relative" pages in a pagelabel can be converted to absolute pages:

```bash
cat <<'EOF' | tee relpage.sh
#!/bin/bash
PDFFILE=$1
STR=$2
PAGELABENR=${STR%:*}
PAGENRINLABEL=${STR#*:}
PAGELABELINDEX=$(qpdf --json ${PDFFILE} | jq -r .pagelabels[$PAGELABENR].index)
ABSPAGENR=$(($PAGELABELINDEX+$PAGENRINLABEL))
echo $ABSPAGENR
EOF
chmod +x relpage.sh
```

Usage: `./relpage.sh inputfile.pdf 1:17`. Note that pagelabels are 0-based.

To extract pages 17 to 39 in the pagelabel 1 use following command:

```bash
qpdf \
    --empty \
    --pages \
    ${INPUTFILE} \
    $(./relpage.sh ${INPUTFILE} 1:17)-$(./relpage.sh ${INPUTFILE} 1:39) \
    -- \
    output.pdf
```

To get the pagelabels info just use `qpdf --json --json-key=pagelabels inputfile.pdf` or the following

```
$ INPUTFILE=inpufile.pdf
$ PAGELABELSLENGHT=$(qpdf --json ${INPUTFILE} | jq -r '.pagelabels | length')
$ echo "file '${INPUTFILE}' has ${PAGELABELSLENGHT} pagelabels"
$ for i in $(seq 0 $((${PAGELABELSLENGHT}-1))); \
  do echo "pagelevel #$i starts at index #$(qpdf --json ${INPUTFILE} | jq -r .pagelabels[$i].index)"; \
  done

file 'inpufile.pdf' has 2 pagelabels
pagelevel #0 starts at index #0
pagelevel #1 starts at index #4
```